# Query mongo database from application not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

So I'm using Express and passport to create an application. So far so good, but the issue I have is when I try to look something up in my mongo database. From the mongodb i can add and query the database from the console, but when I try to add or query from within express I have problems. As you can see below I have my model and then require it in my `passport.js` file. When I do `User.findOne()` it returns `null` for variables `user` and `err`. I'm not sure where to go from here because I know the data is there I just can't query it from my app.

models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    local: {
        username: String,
        password: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('./models/user.js');

module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use('local-registration', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password'
    }, function(username, password, done) {
        console.log('credentials', username, password);
        User.findOne({ 'local.username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
            console.log(user,err);
        });
        done();
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Try moving your `done()` into the `User.findOne` callback. E.g., right after `console.log(user, err)`.

Comment: So, I did that and got this as my output http://i.imgur.com/QyDh7fe.png

Comment: Looks like it's working now (the console is logging `null` for user and `null` for err). You were calling `done()` before the callback function completed.

Comment: Alright, but how do I know if I found a match? Because I have a user in my DB as max.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});
```

**user._id** is a correct generated id in mongodb. !